# Make a TELNET CONNECTION exposed as a Virtual COM to the OS

Tags: serial-port, telnet

I have a Window application that can be connected to a device through Serial Port.

I would like to have a sort of remotization of the device.

To Do this the device is connected to a remote board with a processor that run Linux OS and I'm using Ser2Net to transport serial communication to Ethernet Protocol.

Of course if I connect it via Telnet I can connect the remote device but this is not my target.

I have a Windows application, as mentioned before, and the only way to connect it to the system is via COM port.

Is there any easy-way to make this serial over ethernet be spawned as a Virtual COM?

Thank you!
Ale_Trex

Comment: This article may be helpful. [WINDOWS - ComPort over Network](https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c#windows)

Comment: Hi there, this answer completely to my issues. I have tested it and it works fine. Thanks a lot kunif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as kunif just commented my post (thank you again) I would like to share the info as an answer to make everybody has my problem, able to fix it properly.

Following this link you'll get instruction that make you able to spawn a virtual COM to connect to an APP can be link to a generic serial over ethernet.

[WINDOWS - ComPort over Network](https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/e0c669608466470baa6c#windows)

This works fine with me. Hope it works with you too.

PS. instruction would introduce you to both Windows or Linux approach to the issue.

Ale_Trex